# Index of list item from ant property

Tags: list, ant, ant-contrib

I have a ant parameter with list of values as below.

```
releases=release1,release2
```

I use the below for loop to process the values.

```
<for list="${releases}" param="release">
  <sequential>
    <echo>Processing @{release}</echo>
  </sequential>
<for>
```

I want to do something like, I want to echo the below statement only when the @{release}=release2

```
<echo>Processing last release</echo>
```

I am not quite sure how to get the index of the list items or if it is even possible.

Thanks in advance,
Balaji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's all? And, you're using Ant-Contrib tasks already. Take a look at the [PropertyRegEx](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html) task. That's the Ant-Contrib task that will do exactly what you want:

```
<propertyregex property="last.release"
     input="${releases}"
     regexp=".*,(.*)"
     select="\1"/>
```

This will set `${last.release}` to the last release in your string.

Be careful of strings that are null or don't match your regular expression! You can use the Ant-Contrib `if` task to test for that:

```
<propertyregex property="last.release"
     input="${releases}"
     regexp=".*,(.*)"
     select="\1"/>
<if>
    <isset property="last.release"/>
    <then>
        <echo>The last release is ${last.release}</echo>
    </then>
    <else>
        <fail>Oops! Something didn't work...</fail>
    </else>
</if>
```

Comment: Thnx David... I managed to tweak that a bit to suit my reqs and it worked!!